# Map-summing items in a multidimensional array

Tags: python

I have an array that looks roughly like this:

```
[ (0.5, 0.6, 0.7), (0.1, 0.9, 0.8), (0.9, 1.0, 0.4),
  ...
  (0.3, 0.8, 0.3), (0.2, 0.4, 0.9), (0.5, 0.5, 0.3) ]
```

What I need is a sum of [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], etc. as well as [1][0], [1][1], [1][2], etc. I need a way to get a sum of the first index of all items in the array, then a sum of the second index of all items in the array, etc.

How can I do this in Python? The ultimate result would be to have a single tuple that contained the average of each index of all of the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> c=[ (0.5, 0.6, 0.7), (0.1, 0.9, 0.8), (0.9, 1.0, 0.4),(0.5, 0.6, 0.7), (0.1, 0.9, 0.8), (0.9, 1.0, 0.4),(0.5, 0.6, 0.7), (0.1, 0.9, 0.8), (0.9, 1.0, 0.4)]
>>> [ sum([t[i] for t in c]) for i in range(len(c[0]))]
[4.5, 7.5, 5.6999999999999993]
```

This assumes all tuples have has many elements as your first tuple

Comment: Nice :) That worked great. Sorry, I'm jetlagged and couldn't think this one through myself :P

Answer (score 1):

This should do for arbitrary sized tuples:

```
result = reduce(lambda x, y: tuple((xi + yi) for (xi, yi) in zip (x, y)), l)
```

with `l` being the list of tuples. Of course, that only sums everything up, doesn't calculate the average.

Any reason why you're not doing this with NumPy. It would simplify (and speed up) things.

Comment: +1 for `zip` then it's good for tuples of any length, so long as they match.

Answer (score 0):

python 2.6.x

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1], x[2]+y[2]), [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (4, 5, 6)])
(7, 10, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuple(a.sum(axis=0))`
if a is the array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
values = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
print map(sum, values)
```